# Tips on decreasing network shuffle in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I have this use case where I am joining two dataframes in Spark, `A` and `B`.

```
A -> Huge dataframe approx size: 100 TB
B -> Smaller dataframe approx size: 100 MB
```

Two questions:

1. How to reduce network shuffle as spark UI showed shuffle read of about 30gb.
2. The number of tasks is also huge approx 1,000,000. Any tips to reduce them?

I have tried caching dataframe `A`, but surprisingly it only made the job slower.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post spark ui and aslo you code if possible

Comment: @Srinivas I'm afraid I cant as its not my personal code. Anyway the code is more theoretical and doesn't do much expect for the join.

Comment: ok, It also depending on how you are using joins inside your code.. can you post your spark-submit command ??

Comment: Broadcasting might help you if it is only 100MB join table: 
 https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins-broadcast.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try increasing [`autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options) to 100MB in order to trigger a map-side join, or if that doesn't help, to explicitly broadcast your `B` (smaller) dataframe:

```
val result = dfA.join(broadcast(dfB),...
```

That should eliminate join-related shuffle completely.

Comment: Will try this out and let you know. Thanks.